# Storing drawn canvas components into an array

Tags: java, android

Is there any possible way to put all the drawn objects into an array? This is just for a drawing game so it is possible to save all objects and load them back from this way.
Thanks if this is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Picture` class - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html

After it's being attached to the canvas, it records all drawing operations and stores it.
After you can either draw all of them on another canvas, or store/transfer the Picture to make it on another device or later.

**UPD**: something like this

```
    Picture picture = new Picture();
    Canvas canvas = picture.beginRecording(300, 300);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(5, 5, 10, 10), new Paint()); // configure paint here
    picture.endRecording();

    picture.writeToStream(new FileOutputStream("stored_drawing.pict"));
```

Now you'll be able to restore this rectangle from file and draw it on any another canvas.
So generally you can wrap you user's drawing through this class and it wil store all user drawing operations.

Good luck

Comment: How am I meant to use this though?